# Struts2 Jquery Plugin : proposal for an autocompleter doesn't reduce

Tags: json, struts2-jquery

My autocompleter

```
<sj:autocompleter
id="auto"
name="credit"
href="%{url}"
list="objectsList"
listValue="name" 
listKey="id" 
delay="50"
loadMinimumCount="2"
forceValidOption="false"
onChangeTopics="autocompleteChange"
onFocusTopics="autocompleteFocus"
onSelectTopics="autocompleteSelect"
/>
```

recognizes the json source but when typing a value it highlights the result without reducing the list (700 members long so it's impossible to use).

Answer (score 0):

This works implementing a term attribute in the json action and filtering the result on it.